# How to use enumerate in a list comprehension with two lists?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, bioinformatics

I just started to use list comprehension and I'm struggling with it. In this case, I need to get the `n` number of each list (`sequence_0` and `sequence_1`) that the iteration is at each time. How can I do that?

The idea is to get the longest sequence of equal nucleotides (a motif) between the two sequences. Once a pair is finded, the program should continue in the nexts nucleotides of the sequences, checking if they are also equal and then elonganting the motif with it. The final output should be an list of all the motifs finded.
The problem is, to continue in the next nucleotides once a pair is finded, i need the position of the pair in both sequences to the program continue. The `index` function does not work in this case, and that's why i need the enumerate.

Also, I don't understand exactly the reason for the `x` and `y` between `()`, it would be good to understand that too :)

just to explain, the content of the lists is DNA sequences, so its basically something like:

```
sequence_1 = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'C']
```

```
def find_shared_motif(arq):
    data = fastaread(arq)
    seqs = [list(sequence) for sequence in data.values()]
    motifs = [[]]
    i = 0
    sequence_0, sequence_1 = seqs[0], seqs[1]  # just to simplify

    for x, y in [(x, y) for x in zip(sequence_0[::], sequence_0[1::]) for y in zip(sequence_1[::], sequence_1[1::])]:
        print(f'Pairs {"".join(x)} and {"".join(y)} being analyzed...')
        if x == y:
            print(f'Pairs {"".join(x)} and {"".join(y)} match!')
            motifs[i].append(x[0]), motifs[i].append(x[1])
            k = sequence_0.index(x[0]) + 2  # NAO ESTA DEVOLVENDO O NUMERO CERTO
            u = sequence_1.index(y[0]) + 2
            print(k, u)

            # Determines if the rest of the sequence is compatible
            print(f'Starting to elongate the motif {x}...')
            for j, m in enumerate(sequence_1[u::]):
                try:
                    # Checks if the nucleotide is equal for both of the sequences
                    print(f'Analyzing the pair {sequence_0[k + j]}, {m}')
                    if m == sequence_0[k + j]:
                        motifs[i].append(m)
                        print(f'The pair {sequence_0[k + j]}, {m} is equal!')

                    # Stop in the first nonequal residue
                    else:
                        print(f'The pair {sequence_0[k + j]}, {m} is not equal.')
                        break

                except IndexError:
                    print('IndexError, end of the string')

        else:
            i += 1
            motifs.append([])

        return motifs
...
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to enumerate? What output do you expect?

Comment: Putting `x, y` inside `()` makes a tuple of the two values.

Comment: There's no need to make copies of the sequences with `[::]`

Comment: You can use `for ix, x in enumerate(zip(...)) for iy, y in enumerate(...)`

Comment: Please add a sample of the output desired to your question.

Comment: I tried to update the question to be more clear.

Comment: Please add working code and sample input and output so we can reproduce and help. [MRE]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go with it is to start zipping both lists:

```py
a = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'C']
b = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T']

c = list(zip(a,b))
```

In that case, `c` will have the list of tuples below

```
c = [('A','A'), ('T','T'), ('C','C'), ('A','C'), ('C','T')]
```

Then, you can go with list comprehension and `enumerate`:

```py
d = [(i, t) for i, t in enumerate(c)]
```

This will bring something like this to you:

```py
d = [(0, ('A','A')), (1, ('T','T')), (2, ('C','C')), ...]
```

Of course you can go for a one-liner, if you want:

```py
d = [(i, t) for i, t in enumerate(zip(a,b))]
>>> [(0, ('A','A')), (1, ('T','T')), (2, ('C','C')), ...]
```

Now, you have to deal with the nested tuples. Focus on the internal ones. It is obvious that what you want is to compare the first element of the tuples with the second ones. But, also, you will need the position where the difference resides (that lies outside). So, let's build a function for it. Inside the function, `i` will capture the positions, and `t` will capture the inner tuples:

```
def compare(a, b):
    d = [(i, t) for i, t in enumerate(zip(a,b))]
    for i, t in d:
        if t[0] != t[1]:
            return i
        return -1
```

In that way, if you get `-1` at the end, it means that all elements in both lists are equal, side by side. Otherwise, you will get the position of the *first* difference between them.

It is important to notice that, in the case of two lists with different sizes, the `zip` function will bring a list of tuples with the size matching the smaller of the lists. The extra elements of the other list will be ignored.

Ex.

```py
list(zip([1,2], [3,4,5]))
>>> [(1,3), (2,4)]
```

You can use the function `compare` with your code to get the positions where the lists differ, and use that to build your motifs.

Comment: Thanks for the ashwer! i actually learned from this. The problem is the motif maybe not be in the same position for both sequences. In your resolution its seems the first element of the first list will only be compare to the first element of the second list, but i actully need it to be compare to all the elements.

Comment: Nice! Well, it is possible to work something out using _slicing_. If you use `compare` passing the motif and a slice of the sequence, it seems that could work. `compare(motif, a)`, then `compare(motif, a[1:])`, `compare(motif, a[2:])` ... maybe doing it in a loop of the size of the entire sequence. This way, you will always be comparing the motif with a different piece of the sequence, as if you were sliding through it.